# how can we have a 31-day old site with >14k views, but only 138 visits/day?

Tags: discussion, area-51, economics

The [economics beta site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics) is now 31 days old, and has, Area51 reports, had just **138** visits per day on average.  But this question alone - [Long term trade data request](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/437/104) - has had over 14k views - which is equivalent to over **400** visits for each of the 31 days that the site has been open.

How can that be? Does the area51 counting-algorithm crop the highest-viewed questions at a certain number of views, for the purposes of calculating visits/day?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The "visits/day" number is the median number of daily visits for the past two weeks. Traffic from HN causes a spike for a day or two, but does not affect the median that much.

Comment: this is correct

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't call it "visits/day" if your calculation is nothing resembling visits divided by days...

Comment: Is this correct as of 2013?